# kdenlive video editor not working drag and drop

Tags: 20.04, video-editor, drag-and-drop

when I try to edit a video in kdenlive , in my folder where video clips are stored I open the file and simply try to drag and drop it to kdenlive , but it's not work or I do not know how to do it , and my secondary HDD not showing when I import file ,if copy files paset in SSD which is my primary drive then kdenlive showing to as a  import file ...
plz any one can solve this issue?